# Removing footnote of aomart

Tags: header-footer, overleaf

This is the bottom of the first page when I'm using aomart package for writing latex in Overleaf. I want to delete this because I just want to just the package to write mathematic equations and I have a look at the removing header already but it still has this. How can I do it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you post your code here-- so that the error can be more clearly seen ?  I don't see any footnote when I use this [minimal `aomart` implementation](https://i.imgur.com/glsJ52Q.png) to type a pair of equations !

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
\documentclass{aomart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
The above are my headers and I use this in https://www.overleaf.com/

Answer (score 1):

this instruction helps:

```
\copyrightnote{}
```

I get this from https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aomart/aomart.pdf , page 6